# variable in style and pug settings

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, pug

Is it possible to pass a variable in a style tag and pug bemto settings?
I need generate prefix for html elements and compile css for them.
Somethink like this.

```
<template lang="pug">
    include ../src/libs/bemto/bemto.pug
    - set_bemto_settings({ prefix: classPrefix, modifier: '--' })

    +b.button
        +e.value

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                classPrefix: 'test-'
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    $prefix: classPrefix;

    .#{$prefix}button{
        color: #000;
         &__value{
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }

</style>
```

And it will compile in 
html:

```
<div class="test-button">
    <div class="test-button__value"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.test-button{
    color: #000;
}
.test-button__value{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Pug mixin documentation? You can pass arguments through them.

Comment: I looked, but i dont understand how it use for bemto settings.